# Is there a way to grab url of open tab in chrome using Python?

Tags: python

```
f = open('C:/Users/McCracken/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User 
Data/Default/History', 'rb')
data = f.read()
print(data)
f.close()
f = open('C:/Users/McCracken/Desktop/URL', 'w')
f.write(repr(data))
f.close()
```

I understand there are ways to open given urls using libraries such as webbrowser and selenium, but I need to grab from already running tab. I considered using chrome history stored in Chrome/User Data/Default/History, but seems not live.

- Is chrome history updated live to AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History?

  - If so then this might be my solution and I am not properly grabbing its data. If chrome history is updated live, and this is the correct approach, how could I sqllite3 query this to grab an open tab/most recent tab?
- If not then any suggestions are well appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?